# Php multiple generated files open with multiple tabs (Mpdf, Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using **Mpdf** library (Html to Pdf generator) inside **Codeigniter**.
It generate well. Problem is when try to open multiple generated file with newtab.

**Problem (problem *** marked):**

```
$pdfFilePath1 = FCPATH."/upload/report/1.pdf";
$pdfFilePath2 = FCPATH."/upload/report/2.pdf";

//1 pdf generate
ini_set('memory_limit','32M'); 
$header = $this->load->view('header', $data, true);
$footer = $this->load->view('footer', $data, true);
$html = $this->load->view('main_htm_f', $data, true);
$this->load->library('pdf');
$pdf = $this->pdf->load();
$pdf->ignore_invalid_utf8 = true;
$pdf->SetHTMLHeader($header1);
$pdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer1);
$pdf->AddPage('', '', '', '', '', 15, 15, 30, 30, 10, 10);
$pdf->WriteHTML($html1);
$pdf->Output($pdfFilePath1, 'F');

***Here $pdfFilePath1  will be open with newtab & execution will be running***

//2 pdf generate
ini_set('memory_limit','32M'); 
$header = $this->load->view('header', $data, true);
$footer = $this->load->view('footer', $data, true);
$html = $this->load->view('main_htm_s', $data, true);
$this->load->library('pdf');
$pdf = $this->pdf->load();
$pdf->ignore_invalid_utf8 = true;
$pdf->SetHTMLHeader($header1);
$pdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer1);
$pdf->AddPage('', '', '', '', '', 15, 15, 30, 30, 10, 10);
$pdf->WriteHTML($html1);
$pdf->Output($pdfFilePath2, 'F');

***And Here $pdfFilePath2  will be open with newtab and execution will be stop***
```

> Actually problem is little may be, but i failed to solve.

Comment: You can take all pdf name in array and in looping you can put your open with newtab code.so mpdf code run only once but open multiple file in diffrent tabs.

Comment: is it possible to download and create multiple files at once?